# Automatically generate method in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

Note in the following code the function called `employee_dictionary()` has not been created yet. If I highlight the error symbol next to the line number then the options I get from the Eclipse IDE are: `function 'employee_dictionary' could not be resolved` and `'employee_dictionary' was not declared in this scope`.

I assumed I would be presented with the option of having Eclipse create this function automatically to resolve the error. Now I am left wondering if there is something fundamentally wrong with my code or if Eclipse does not have the functionality I am looking for.

I am new to c++ and Eclipse, and I am building this Employee class because it is usually where I start when I want to learn a new language; help resolving the issue would be appreciated. I want an IDE that has this capability so before I get to deep if I need to switch IDE's I will.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    int id;
    int salary;
public:
    Employee(int new_id, int new_salary)
    {
        id = new_id;
        salary = new_salary;
    }

    void setID(int newInt)
    {

        if (employee_dictonary(newInt) == 0)
        {
            id = newInt;
        }
    }

    int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    void setSalary(int newInt)
    {
        salary = newInt;
    }

    int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Normally IDEs don't generate code for you. And if they do it's usually a manual option that you have to click on. Not part of a compile process. In Visual Studio I have a paid ($100) addon called VisualAssist that does this for me when I right click on the missing function and use a context menu. Of course for $100 it does more than just that.

Comment: I know C++ QtCreator can do it. C# Visual studio can do it. Don't know if Eclipse can do it. Use the Context Menu if possible.

Comment: Here, please: `int employee_dictionary(int) { return 42; }`

Comment: I wouldn't choose an IDE based on that feature. I would choose the IDE based on the debugger it provides, and if need on the auto completion. Writing `int employee_dictionary(int) {}` at the place where you want it is not such a big deal, but using an IDE with a broken or not well working debugger is a nightmare.

Comment: @t.niese Really hoping I can have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: Eclipse only auto-generates getters and setters for class members as far as I know. The function `employee_dictionary` is not a method of the `Employee` class so you have to define it on your own.

Comment: @Carlton fml dude that's A LOT of work... I dont know if I am cut out for this. My mom was right, I should have been a baker.

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare employee_dictionary as a function. You're trying to call a function that hasn't been defined yet. This is the same as trying to use a variable that you haven't defined

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::cout<<bob; // bob is not declared
}

In function 'int main()':
9:16: error: 'bob' was not declared in this scope
```